# Wrong date returned by get_the_time

Tags: date

I have this line of code :

```
$registration_date = get_the_time('F j, Y').' at '.get_the_time('g:i a');
```

I just ran this on my BlueHost hosted website and it returned : January 29, 2013 at 12:54 pm

However, on the same site I can see in the dashboard that post publication dates are correct.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more clearly...

Comment: Yes. The problem is that today is not 29th of January :) the get_the_time('F j, Y') call should return today's date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[get_the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) function returns the time of the current post within loop.

If you want to display today's date then use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of core php.